# Can I use cancan with many resources?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I use devise and created two models, Doctor and Patient.
When I write `load_and_authorize_resource` cancan gives an exception

```
undefined local variable or method `current_user
```

How can I use cancan for both of them?

Answer (score 4):

There is a method called `current_ability` in the Application Controller, you can simply overwrite it.

[Changing current_ability documentation](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Changing-Defaults)

It will look something like this

```
def current_ability
  @current_ability ||= Ability.new(current_user)
end
```

But you may change it to

```
def current_ability
  if current_doctor
    @current_ability ||= Ability.new(current_doctor)
  else
    @current_ability ||= Ability.new(current_patient)
  end
end
```

That will allow the initialize method in the app/models/ability.rb to recieve either the current_patient or the current_doctor depending on the case.
You could customize it to look something like this

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(resource)
    if resource.class == Patient
      can, Read Something
      can, Edit Other
      .
      .
      .
    else
      can, Read Something
      can, Edit Other
      .
      .
      .
    end
      .
      .
      .
```

I hope this help, you can also see the cancan [Full doc](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan)

Answer (score 0):

You can find a complete configuration of Devise and Cancan here: [Part 1](http://www.tonyamoyal.com/2010/07/28/rails-authentication-with-devise-and-cancan-customizing-devise-controllers/) [Part 2](http://www.tonyamoyal.com/2010/09/29/rails-authentication-with-devise-and-cancan-part-2-restful-resources-for-administrators/)

Comment: thnx.
but just need to define method(in my case with devise for :doctors and devise_for :patients)
def current_user
return current_doctor || current_patient
end

Comment: Yes it was just an overall help because maybe it wasn't the only thing missing.